# iOS adding objects to NSDictionary and accessing the objects in the NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I want to add objects to a nsdictionary and access those objects or modify the properties in the object but I'm having trouble getting them.

for example:

```
ObjectClass:

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.firstName = @"";
        self.lastName = @"";
    }
    return self;
}


    mainClass:

    ObjectClass *myObject = [ObjectClass allo] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *listOfClients = [NSMutableDictionary allo] init];

    [self.listOfClients setObject:myObject forKey:@"firstClient"];

    (lldb) po [listOfClients valueForKey:@"firstClient"]
    $5 = 0x0683e140 <myObject: 0x683e140>
    (lldb) po [_testDic valueForKey:@"firstClient.myObject"]
    $6 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

How can access for example the firstName of firstClient?

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

First, you've got a naming conflict with your `listOfClients` local variable and your property.  Try something like this:

```
self.listOfClients = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

ObjectClass *myObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];
myObject.firstName = @"John";
myObject.lastName = @"Smith";

self.listOfClients[@"firstClient"] = myObject;
```

This will accomplish initializing the dictionary and an object and placing the object in the dictionary.  Then later you can access the item like this:

```
ObjectClass *obj = (ObjectClass *)self.listOfClients[@"firstClient"];
NSLog(@"Name: %@ %@", obj.firstName, obj.lastName);
```

Comment: in your example how to I add a secondClient in the same dictionary?

Comment: Create another object, say `obj2`.  Then do the same thing: `self.listOfClients[@"secondClient"] = obj2`.  Does that help?  Perhaps it would be more helpful if you could describe more fully what you're trying to do.  This setup seems a bit awkward, so there may be a better way to achieve your ultimate goals.

Answer (score 0):

I totally miss this:

[listOfClients valueForKeyPath:@"firstClient.lastName"];